# The right way to hand over an object to a view?

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller, nsobject

i'm a bit new to iphone development. I made it to develop a nice App which loads XML Data from a feed, displays this data in a UITableView and if a user taps a row there should be a detail view which displays the data.

Thats where i got stuck a little bit. It's not clear for me how to hand over the data of the entry selected by the user to my detail view. The Detail-View is called via presentModalView...

I thought about:

1. Calling a "setDetails:(PostingData *)myPosting" function of the viewController of my detail view.
2. presenting the detailView to the user by calling presentModalViewAnimated.

The view is presented, but the setDetails: function crashes without any output to the debugger console.

MY QUESTION:

What is the right way to hand over Data (in custom objects as instance of a self written class) from my view Controller to a View Controller which should display detail data.

Any hint or help is appreciated. I can't pay you for your help, but i'm on my way becoming better and then helping others too :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. define the custom object in your class.  `@property(nonatomic, retain) MyClass * myClass;`
2. load the feed into a NSMutableDictionary and provide that to your class

> ```
> [YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER *yourViewController = [[YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER alloc] init];
> yourViewController.PROPERTY_DEFINED_BEFORE = yourObject;
> [view addSubview:yourViewController.view];
> [yourViewController release];
> ```

cheers

Answer (score 4):

Method 1: Pass it in custom init method

In your Header File declare a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id myDataObject;
```

And in your implementation use a custom init like this

```
 -(id)initCustom:(id)myObject;
    if(self = [super init]) {
        myDataObject = [myObject retain];
    }
    return self;
  }
```

Method 2: Use a property

Use @property in your Header
and @synthesize in your .m Implementation File

```
   [CustomUIViewController* newViewController = [[CustomUIViewControlleralloc] init];
   newViewConroller.myDataObject = myObject;
   [view addSubview:newViewController.view];
   [newViewController release];
```

Comment: The first way misses a retain call.

Comment: ok. That works like a charm with method 1. But there is one thing that makes problems. The Detail-View is now opened and i can display the data. If i try to access the object from an IBAction thats called from a button tap, i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Do i have to hand over the object to my initCustom Method in a speacial way?

Comment: did you used @property (nonatomic, retain) ..this should retain your object once

Comment: yes, i did. in @interface "jobs *theJob" and in outside of interface @property (nonatomic, retain) jobs *theJob; And also in .m - File the @synthesize theJob;

Comment: ah .. ok .. for me to understand that means, that the viewController puts +1 to the retain count to prevent that "myObject" gets released by the viewController which initialised the detailView ?

Comment: ok. thanks. i don't have to dealloc myObject then anywhere ? the retain count is decreased automatically if the viewController for the detail view is deallocaed ?

Comment: call [myObject release] in your dealloc method